# iOS: setting default value for UISwitch

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I have some issue with default value for my switch. I added a FirstSwitchValue to UsersDefaults and this function works:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FirstSwitchValue"]) {
   NSLog(@"Exists");
 }
 else {
   NSLog(@"Not Exists");
 }
}
```

My switch looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)FirstSwitch:(id)sender {

 UISwitch *FirstSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
 // saving data
 if (FirstSwitch.on == YES) {
   [self setParamWithName:@"tag" withValue:@"1"];
 }
 else {
   [self setParamWithName:@"tag" withValue:@"0"];
 }
}
```

If I add

```
[FirstSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
```

in `viewDidLoad` method I receive error message that I use undeclared identifier `FirstSwitch`. After adding declaration like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *FirstSwitch;
```

my `FirstSwitch` stopped working. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you make a connection between the control and `FirstSwitch` property?

Comment: Through Interface Builder

Comment: In connections inspector only Value changed is connected to ViewController FirstSwitch. Should I have more connections ?

Comment: Ok this was the key to resolve my issue. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

You have not synthesized your property manually.  You have 3 options:

1: Use the autosynthesized name: `_FirstSwitch`.  You then can use this:

```
[_FirstSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
```

2: Call the getter function.  You can use either:

```
[self.FirstSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
```

or

```
[[self FirstSwitch] setOn:YES animated:YES];
```

3: Synthesize the property yourself.  First create an instance variable:

```
//something.h
@interface somethingClass : UIViewController {
    UISwitch *FirstSwitch;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *FirstSwitch;
```

Then synthesize it in your .m

```
//something.m
@synthesize FirstSwitch = _FirstSwitch;
```

And your code should work as is after that.

I recommend you read Apple's documentation about [properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html).

Comment: I used your third example and my switch does't read default value. I have no errors.

Comment: In my .h file: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *FirstSwitch;

- (IBAction)FirstSwitch:(id)sender;` In my .m file: `@synthesize FirstSwitch = _FirstSwitch;` in viewDidLodad: `[_FirstSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];`

Comment: Try putting the setOn: part in viewDidAppear and if that doesn't work try changing it from `weak` to `strong`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have make property then use as `self.FirstSwitch`

Answer (score 0):

- First, give right name to your objects, firstSwitch.
- Second, if you want to use your property, use it like [self.firstSwitch do something].

Hope it helps you.